# Shift a sequence of bytes by N bits. Assembly language

Tags: assembly, x86-64

How to left shift or right shift a sequence of bytes by specified number of bits? Suggestions ?

Comment: What you have done so far ?

Comment: For my particular case, I found out a different way to achieve my goal. I must xor two strings with relative shift and I use address offset. But my solution to my problem is not the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://board.flatassembler.net/topic.php?t=19767

> Have a look at `shld` and `shrd`. You can chain them together to make
>   multiple {q|d}word shifts. If the shift amount is more than 32 bits
>   (or 64 bits for 64-bit code) then shift by whole units and add the
>   `sh{l|r}d` to the last few bits.

Answer (score 0):

There are instructions like **shl** (shift left) and **shr** (shift right) that you could use.

For example:

shl $2, r0   which means shift all the bits of the value stored in register zero by 2 in the left direction.

Comment: These instructions do shift a sequence of _bits_, not a sequence of _bytes_. E.g.: how about a sequence of 20 bytes?

Comment: Register is a limited sequence of bytes... I want more =)